# How to reorganize data in columns into new columns by categories

Tags: r, database

We have collected over 130000 of plant phenology observations during the summer and entered the data into Excel. Each observation included between 1 and 6 categorical variables describing the different aspects of the plants phenology. For example, I might collect one observation for a birch tree - growing leaves, or I might collect two observations for a birch tree - leaves grown and flowering.

Unfortunately, I have created a data nightmare by NOT collecting the categorical codes in a logical order on the datasheet and thus entered them in Excel not reflecting the categories of phenology codes (i.e. Other, Leaf-out, Flowering, Fruit, Leaf senescence, Leaf abscission)

Here is what my data looks like (sample data for R found at bottom of question):

[image]

Here is what my data should look like:

[image]

I have created a spreadsheet with all of my phenology codes and their associated phenology categories (again, Other, Leaf-out, Flowering, Fruit, Leaf senescence, Leaf abscission).

I would like to use my phenology codes spreadsheet which I have imported into R (see code at bottom) to reorganize my dataset into the logical format shown above. I can do this by creating each of the new fields and then writing extensive conditional statements (not needing the phenology codes spreadsheet!), but I do not know how to efficiently use my data and the phenology codes to reorganize my data fast and efficiently.

Finally, in my phenology codes spreadsheet I have created a rank field to deal with the fact that sometime my technicians recorded two observations in the same category. In this case the highest number or rank should always prevail.

```
Sample.Data <- structure(list(Species = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E","F", "G", "H", "I", 
               "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T"), 
               Code.1 = c("C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
               "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), 
               Code.2 = c("V", "0", "rf", "0", "0", "0", "uf", "uf", "uf", "uf", "0", "0", "0", 
               "0", "uf", "uf", "0", "0", "0", "0"), Code.3 = c("g3", "gd", "r3", "r3", "r3", "r3", 
               "V", "V", "V", "V", "g1", "gd", "vd", "g1", "V", "V", "g1", "r3", "r3", "r3"), 
               Code.4 = c("vd", "vd", "vd", "vd", "vd", "vd", "g3", "g3", "g3", "g3", "vd", "vd", "r2", 
               "vd", "g1", "vd", "vd", "vd", "vd", "vd"), 
               Code.5 = c("L2", "L1", "L1", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L3", "L2", "L3", "L2", "L2", 
               "L3", "L1", "L1", "L2", "L1", "L1", "L2"), 
               Code.6 = c("K", "K", "K", "K", "b1", "b3", "b2", "K", "K", "b4", "K", "K", "K", "b1", 
               "b3", "Y", "Z", "Y", "K", "b1")), .Names = c("Species", "Code.1", "Code.2", 
               "Code.3", "Code.4", "Code.5", "Code.6"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")

Pheno.Codes <- structure(list(`Pheno Code` = c("Y", "0", "Z", "A", "B1", "B2", 
               "C", "FA", "As", "Af", "R", "Rs", "Rf", "Ra", "K", "w", "m", "mw", 
               "wm", "st", "b", "b1", "b2", "b3", "b2", "b4", "uf", "rd", "rf", 
               "V", "VL", "Vb", "gd", "gb", "g1", "g2", "g3", "ed", "r", "r1", 
               "r2", "r3", "vd", "vt", "L", "L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "X"), 
               `Pheno Category` = c("Other", "Other", "Leaf-out", "Leaf-out", 
               "Leaf-out", "Leaf-out", "Leaf-out", "Flowering", "Flowering", 
               "Flowering", "Flowering", "Flowering", "Flowering", "Flowering", 
               "Flowering", "Flowering", "Flowering", "Flowering", "Flowering", 
               "Flowering", "Flowering", "Flowering", "Flowering", "Flowering", 
               "Flowering", "Flowering", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", "Fruit", 
               "Fruit", "Fruit", "Leaf senescence", "Leaf senescence", 
               "Leaf senescence", "Leaf senescence", "Leaf senescence", 
               "Leaf senescence", "Leaf senescence", "Leaf senescence", 
               "Leaf senescence", "Leaf senescence", "Leaf senescence", 
               "Leaf senescence", "Leaf abscission", "Leaf abscission", 
               "Leaf abscission", "Leaf abscission", "Leaf abscission", 
               "Other"), Rank = c(0, 0.1, 0.5, 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2, 2, 2.1, 2, 
               2, 2.1, 2.3, 2, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, NA, 2.3, NA, 
               2.5, 3, 3.1, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 3.3, 4, 4, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4, 4.4, 
               4.5, 4.6, 4.7, 4.8, 4.9, 5, 5, 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 6)), .Names = c("Pheno Code", 
               "Pheno Category", "Rank"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -50L), 
               class = "data.frame")

Sample.Data2 <- structure(list(Species = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E","F", "G", "H", "I", 
               "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T"), 
               Code.1 = c("C", "C", "B1", "C", "", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
               "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), 
               Code.2 = c("V", "0", "rf", "0", "0", "0", "uf", "uf", "uf", "uf", "0", "", "0", 
               "0", "uf", "uf", "0", "0", "0", "0"), Code.3 = c("g3", "gd", "r3", "r3", "r3", "r3", 
               "V", "V", "", "V", "g1", "gd", "vd", "g1", "V", "V", "g1", "r3", "r3", "r3"), 
               Code.4 = c("", "vd", "vd", "vd", "vd", "vd", "g3", "g3", "g3", "g3", "vd", "vd", "r2", 
               "qd", "g1", "vd", "vd", "vd", "vd", "vd"), 
               Code.5 = c("L2", "L1", "L1", "L7", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L3", "L2", "L3", "L2", "L2", 
               "L3", "L1", "L1", "L2", "L1", "L1", "L2"), 
               Code.6 = c("", "", "K", "K", "b1", "b6", "b2", "K", "K", "b4", "K", "K", "K", "b1", 
               "b3", "Y", "Z", "Y", "K", "b1")), .Names = c("Species", "Code.1", "Code.2", 
               "Code.3", "Code.4", "Code.5", "Code.6"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution with `data.table`:

```
# load the 'data.table'-package
library(data.table)

# convert both dataframes to data.table's
setDT(Sample.Data)
setDT(Pheno.Codes)

# reshape 'Sample.Data' to long format
sample.long <- melt(Sample.Data, id = 'Species')

# join with 'Pheno.Codes'
# filter/select for each 'Species'/'pheno.cat' combo the row where the rank is equal to the max rank
# reshape the result into wide format again
sample.long[Pheno.Codes, on = c('value' = 'Pheno Code'), `:=` (pheno.cat = `Pheno Category`, rnk = Rank)
            ][, .SD[rnk == max(rnk)], by = .(Species, pheno.cat)
              ][, dcast(.SD, Species ~ pheno.cat, value.var = 'value', fill = '')]
```

which gives:

> ```
>     Species Flowering Fruit Leaf abscission Leaf senescence Leaf-out Other
>  1:       A         K     V              L2              vd        C      
>  2:       B         K                    L1              vd        C     0
>  3:       C         K    rf              L1              vd        C      
>  4:       D         K                    L2              vd        C     0
>  5:       E        b1                    L2              vd        C     0
>  6:       F        b3                    L2              vd        C     0
>  7:       G               V              L2              g3        C      
>  8:       H         K     V              L2              g3        C      
>  9:       I         K     V              L3              g3        C      
> 10:       J        b4     V              L2              g3        C      
> 11:       K         K                    L3              vd        C     0
> 12:       L         K                    L2              vd        C     0
> 13:       M         K                    L2              vd        C     0
> 14:       N        b1                    L3              vd        C     0
> 15:       O        b3     V              L1              g1        C      
> 16:       P               V              L1              vd        C     Y
> 17:       Q                              L2              vd        C     0
> 18:       R                              L1              vd        C     0
> 19:       S         K                    L1              vd        C     0
> 20:       T        b1                    L2              vd        C     0
> ```

---

UPDATE

In response to the specifications as mentioned in the comments, you can adapt the  code to:

```
setDT(Sample.Data2)
setDT(Pheno.Codes)

sample.long <- melt(Sample.Data2, id = 'Species')[value != '']

sample.long[Pheno.Codes, on = c('value' = 'Pheno Code'), `:=` (pheno.cat = `Pheno Category`, rnk = Rank)
            ][is.na(pheno.cat), `:=` (pheno.cat = 'ERROR', rnk = 0)
              ][, .SD[rnk == max(rnk)], by = .(Species, pheno.cat)
                ][, dcast(.SD, Species ~ pheno.cat, value.var = 'value', fill = '')]
```

Comment: @Japp Your solution is excellent. I am still trying to work through two problems to implement it with my complete dataset. In creating this solution I did not (for good reason) include records with incorrect codes (i.e. not found in the 'Pheno Codes' dataset and records with NA (e.g. there is one observation for a species, so columns 'Code 2', 'Code 3', etc. are blank).

Comment: @KeithLarson Glad I could help. What do want to do with record with incorrect codes and with th records with NA-value? Do you want to assign a `pheno.code` anyway?

Comment: @Japp Two things, 1) I would like to remove all the records with a blank value (i.e. ""), e.g. take my sample dataset and put blanks in any of the 'Code' fields to simulate, and 2) create a temporary "Pheno Category" called 'Error', so that I can look up the records and fix the data.

Comment: @KeithLarson Could include some extra example data in your question that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @Japp I have added a second dataset to the bottom of the question called 'Sample.Data2'. Thanks for you help!

Comment: @KeithLarson will look at it later today; btw it is *Jaap* and not *Japp* ;-)

Comment: @KeithLarson no problem, I've seen many Swedes make that mistake ;-) See the update in my answer for a possible solution about how to address your problem

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse` approach you may run the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Reshape `Sample.Data` in long form

```
sample_long <- Sample.Data %>% 
    gather(key=code,value=value,c(Code.1:Code.6)) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    select(-code)
```

Then you join with your `Pheno.Codes`, select max `Rank` by `Species`and `Pheno Category and reshape your data frame:

```
sample_coded <- left_join(sample_long,Pheno.Codes,by=c("value"="Pheno Code")) %>%
    distinct() %>% 
    group_by(Species,`Pheno Category`) %>% 
    filter(Rank==max(Rank)) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    select(-Rank) %>% 
    spread(key=`Pheno Category`,value=value,fill=NA)
```

This is the output:

```
# A tibble: 20 x 7
   Species Flowering Fruit `Leaf-out` `Leaf abscission` `Leaf senescence` Other
 * <chr>   <chr>     <chr> <chr>      <chr>             <chr>             <chr>
 1 A       K         V     C          L2                vd                NA   
 2 B       K         NA    C          L1                vd                0    
 3 C       K         rf    C          L1                vd                NA   
 4 D       K         NA    C          L2                vd                0    
 5 E       b1        NA    C          L2                vd                0    
 6 F       b3        NA    C          L2                vd                0    
 7 G       NA        V     C          L2                g3                NA   
 8 H       K         V     C          L2                g3                NA   
 9 I       K         V     C          L3                g3                NA   
10 J       b4        V     C          L2                g3                NA   
11 K       K         NA    C          L3                vd                0    
12 L       K         NA    C          L2                vd                0    
13 M       K         NA    C          L2                vd                0    
14 N       b1        NA    C          L3                vd                0    
15 O       b3        V     C          L1                g1                NA   
16 P       NA        V     C          L1                vd                Y    
17 Q       NA        NA    C          L2                vd                0    
18 R       NA        NA    C          L1                vd                0    
19 S       K         NA    C          L1                vd                0    
20 T       b1        NA    C          L2                vd                0
```

You may set the value of missing data changing the value of `fill` argument in the last row of the code.